# How can I match two patterns but replace one pattern use sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

There are many lines in a file(test.h),for example:

`#include <stdio.h"  should be converted to #include <stdio.h>`

The first pattern is '#include <', and the second pattern is '.h"', I want use sed in one command line, which match the two patterns at same time, but only replace the second pattern。

I use this command as follow:

```
sed -i 's/include </include </g;s/\.h\"/\.h>/g' test.h
```

but which will replace pattern separately, can't match at the same time.

Comment: Contain input and output example, please, because this sed code do not work.

Comment: Don't use -i when testing sed scripts.

Comment: @MarekNowaczyk Because the quote block use incorrectly. I have modified the script. Thank you

Comment: Post the expected output please

Comment: @123 Thank you, i have backed up the file.

Comment: @sjsam    #include <stdio.h"   -->   #include <stdio.h>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed '/#include </s/\.h"/.h">/' test.h
```

When the line contains `#include <`, replace `.h"` with `.h>`.

Comment: The purpose is：match the 'include <' and '.h"' two patterns at the same time, but replace the second pattern with '.h>'

Comment: That's what this command does : it search lines matching `#include<` and `.h"` on the same line, then substitution is applied to the second match.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -E '/^[[:blank:]]*#include[[:blank:]]*<.*\.h\"$/{s/\"$/>/}' test.h
```

Comment: It seems doesn't work for all cases. some more exmples:

include <stdio.h"  --> include <stdio.h>,
include <stdlib.h"  --> include <stdlib.h>,
include <string.h"  --> include <string.h>,
include <math.h"  --> include <math.h>  etc.

Comment: @user3899306 i was confused about the expected output. The corrected answer should work

Comment: #include "third_party/boost/boost/predef/detail/test.h"
will be changed 
#include "third_party/boost/boost/predef/detail/test.h>
, this is not what is expected to happen.

The purpose is：match the two patterns 'include <' and '.h"' at the same time, but replace the second pattern with '.h>'